# jQuery UI Tooltip Widget auto close

Tags: jquery-ui, tooltip

How i can automaticly close jQuery UI Tooltip Widget after 1 sec.
I use following code:

```
var du=1000;    
$(document).tooltip(
{show:{effect:'slideDown',delay:du,duration:du/2}},
{hide:{effect:'explode',pieces:20,duration:du,delay:du/4}},
{track:true}
);
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var du = 1000;
    $(document).tooltip({
        show: {
            effect: 'slideDown'
        },
        track: true,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $(ui.tooltip).hide('explode');
            }, du);
        }
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nzr4f/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: There is a curious issue I ran into when I used this code to show tooltips in a jQuery UI dialog - if the first form element inside the dialog has a tooltip it causes the form to freeze and the tooltip shows up in the wrong position - the top left hand corner of the window.

Comment: After some more investigation - the vanilla version of the tooptip, $(document).tooltip() works just fine.  The issue is that with tooltips inside dialogs the first form element ends up showing a hugely annoying sticky tooltip. I ran into this thread whilst trying to fix that issue.  Sadly, using a more fully configured tooltip as described in this answer raises the other issue I mention above - the dialog freezes up, the Cancel/Close button no longer works... .  In the end I switched to qTips - which in any case is a whole lot more configurable than the native jQuery UI tiooltip.